# Polymorphic functions and subtypes in julia

Tags: julia

I am learning Julia and for that purpose I am building a simulation of a scheduler for some non specified task. For this I want to create an abstract type, which represents the idea of state. A task could be in any state Accepted, Unfulfilled, Running, Finished:

```
abstract RequestState
```

Then I add some concrete states, which have RequestState as superstate:

```
immutable StateAccepted <: RequestState 
       name :: String 
end
```

And because each state is immutable anyway and it doesn't have an interesting structure, all instances are the same, so I instantiate an instance of the above type to use:

```
const Accepted = StateAccepted("Accepted")
```

I generate this with a macro, perhaps it is relevant.

Now comes the problem. I want to write a function, which checks valid transitions. I only have a skeleton at this point:

```
function checkTransition{T <: RequestState, Q <: RequestState}(t :: T, q :: Q) :: Bool 
  return true 
end
```

I assumed I should read the expression:

```
 T <: RequestState
```

As something like forall T which is a subtype of RequestState, but I think this is wrong.

I would expect that this code compiles. The problem is that I don't understand the error and also can't find anything in the documentation. Note that this could be, because I am unfamiliar with the language. The relevant error is:

```
 Error During Test
  Expression evaluated to non-Boolean
   Expression: checkTransition(Accepted,Running)
   Value: ResourceScheduler.StateRunning("Running")
 ERROR: LoadError: There was an error during testing
   in record(::Base.Test.FallbackTestSet, ::Base.Test.Error) at      ./test.jl:397
    in do_test(::Base.Test.Returned, ::Expr) at ./test.jl:281
    in include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:488
    in process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:262
    in _start() at ./client.jl:318
    while loading /home/eklerks/.julia/v0.5/ResourceScheduler/test/runtests.jl
```

How would I make a generic function accepting only arguments of subtypes of RequestState?

EDIT:

As requested the offending test:

```
@test checkTransition(Accepted, Running)
```

But this didn't work out, because I forgot to update and install my package after I changed it. Before that change it read:

```
function checkTransition{T <: RequestState, Q <: RequestState}(t :: T, q :: Q) :: Q 
    return q 
end
```

Which was the source of the error. Type Q is indeed not a Boolean. I was experimenting with the type system at that moment.

Comment: You need to post the test for us to know why it fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your code should work, typically one writes

```
checkTransition(t::RequestState, q::RequestState) = true
```

instead of using the unnecessary `T <: RequestState` parameterization. Note that `f{T <: X}(::T)` should not be read as "for all `T` subtype of `X`", but rather "there exists `T` subtype of `X`", as this is an [existential type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type) and not a universal type.

The error you're getting is due to `checkTransition(Accepted,Running)` returning a non-boolean, which must be due to a mistake unrelated to the code that you've posted.

Comment: Ah thanks, I knew it had to be something stupid. I added the offending code and documented the mistake I made. And thanks for pointing out that it is not a universal type, which I actually meant to write here.

Comment: That's an interesting comment regarding existential vs universal quantification ... but I'm struggling to think of a practical difference between the two, or a case where this distinction matters in the context of types and julia code. Is there a scenario where declaring T to be a subtype of R will still exclude some subtypes of R from being passed as valid parameters? (obviously, before any such exclusion is made explicit in the subsequent function definition). Or are you simply making a comment on how one should interpret the concept of 'template' types from a semantic point of view?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Existential types and universal types have specific meanings in type theory. An object is of type `Vector{T} where T`, for instance, if there EXISTS a `T` so that the object is of type `Vector{T}`. An object would be of type `Vector{T} for all T` (supposing that existed) if for EVERY `T`, the object is of type `Vector{T}`; in Julia there are no objects that meet that criterion.